# vue data isn`t displayed on a page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, frontend, vuejs3

I started writing the front part of my application using vue.js . And I have a problem with the fact that the data is not output, although if I output it to the console via console.log, everything is displayed correctly. There are no errors in the console.

html part:

```
<div id="app">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Registration time</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<!--                    v-if="users.length > 0">-->
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{user.inputTime}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

script part:

```
<script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                users: []
            }
        },
        async created() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/')
                const data = await response.json()
                console.log(data)
                this.users = data
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    })

    app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

I tried to rewrite this code on 2 versions of vue, but I ran into the same problem. I also tried to fix the code using chat gpt but it didn't help me

Comment: Try `this.user.push(...data);`

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. If data is correct, it should work. ", although if I output it to the console via console.log, everything is displayed correctly" - it's unknown if you evaluated the correctness correctly

Comment: @bassxzero This doesn't matter in any vue version if data is ok. This could reveal a problem if data is not an array, which is one of possibilities.

Comment: @EstusFlask hmmm I thought in vue 2ish, if you reassigned arrays it would break reactivity. I thought you had to use the array methods to manipulate it. `splice, push, etc.`

Comment: @bassxzero Can be a problem for nested properties sometimes, but for users in data() `this.users =` surely causes an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, provide  minimal, reproducible example. Anyway your code works with fake users request:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Registration time</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<!--                    v-if="users.length > 0">-->
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script> 
<script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                users: []
            }
        },
        async created() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                const data = await response.json()
                console.log(data)
                this.users = data
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    })

    app.mount('#app')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I compared the conclusions of our options and realized what the problem was! Replaced `v-for="user in users"` by `v-for="user in users.data"` Thank you man!